# Blank element getting added even when restricted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In [my 'todo list' project here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/90/), the `Add` button needs to be enabled only when the textarea is not blank. For that I have added the code:

```
// show add button only when text is entered
$("#new_todo_item").on("change input propertychange paste", function(){  // line # 64 in JS
    $("#add").prop('disabled' , ! $("#new_todo_item").val().length );
});
```

To reproduce the problem, add the first item, then for second item an empty item is allowed to be added, even at third too.

This part of the code was working earlier. I think because of the further changes made, something is conflicting with this.

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please point me to the corect direction?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/90/)

**EDIT:**

I changed that part of code to:

`$(document).on("change input propertychange paste", "#new_todo_item", function(){ ... });`,

but it did not make any difference.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I changed that part of code to: `$(document).on("change input propertychange paste", "#new_todo_item", function(){ ... });   `, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: yea that was my mistake i was thinking it was something it wasnt, and was meaning the setting of the prop, was thinking you were creating a new input for each new item and was just checking the value length first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After resetting the textarea in `addItem`:

```
// reset the content of textarea
$("#new_todo_item").val("");
```

… just disable the button again:

```
$("#add").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Yeah, that should work. But, shouldn't my code do the same thing? Why is that not working?

Comment: @RahulDesai: Setting `value` programmatically doesn’t trigger any events.